# You need one to take the other

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> Two words are homophones 
>   Both you shall uncover
>   Same in length; close in meaning 
>   You need one to take the other

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps the two words are

> **brake** and **break**.

Two words are homophones 
Both you shall uncover

> Brake and break are homophones. Not sure if the second line has some significance I’m overlooking though.

Same in length; close in meaning

> Brake and break both have 5 letters. Both words refer to stoppages: brakes on a car will cause it to slow down and stop, and a break can stop someone from doing their work.

You need one to take the other

> You might need to put on the *brakes* in order to take a *break*.

Comment: Correct! The second line is part of the question, not the clues

Answer (score 6):

Two words are homophones

> **Compliment** and **complement**

Both you shall uncover

> Both had the [same origin](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/complement-and-compliment-usage-difference): have their roots in the Latin word *complēre*, meaning "to complete."

Same in length; close in meaning

> Both have 10 characters. And refer to praise the other party.

You need one to take the other

> You **compliment** someone for their attire **complement** something.

Comment: Nice answer! You were just a little off in the last clue.

Answer (score 5):

Two words are homophones

> muscle and mussel

Both you shall uncover

> opening the bivalve's shell and working out to reveal a six-pack are both acts of "uncovering"

Same in length; close in meaning

> 6 letters and both derived from "little mouse"

You need one to take the other

> some muscle is required to get to the mussel inside

Comment: Great answer! That is, if it weren't for the third line. Close in meaning is a little different from close in origin :)

Comment: snap! back to the drawing board for me then! :D

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac but the edible part of a mussel is primarily muscle.